# How to define custom colors in tmLanguage.Json in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension for VsCode. I want a specific string pattern to be output at a specific color. I know how to get it output to one of the predefined colors, but I fail to define my own color.

An extract of my json folows

```
"patterns": [
    {
       "name": "invalid.something",
       "match": "\\bFailed\\b"
    },
    {
       "name": "valid.something",
       "match": "\\bPassed\\b",
       "settings": {
            "foreground":"#0f0"
       }
    }
]
```

The pattern "Failed" gets highlighted, as `invalid` is a known identifier, but I cannot get the pattern "Passed" to get highlighted (green).

Answer (score 1):

The grammar defines the scopes of tokens in a file. A [theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers) then maps those scopes to editor colors.

In your case, the theme needs to provide a rule that matches your new scope

```
{
    "scope": "valid.something",
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#0f0"
    }
}
```

You can prototype this using the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` setting in VS Code:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "valid.something",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#0f0"
                    }
                }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did manage to create a new theme with my custom color scope. However doing so overrides the theme the user chose. I would like to just add my scope to any existing theme. Is this possible?

Comment: I solved my issue by (programmatically) adding to the workspace settings directly, as you suggested to do when prototyping. Thanks a lot.